# SQL Server Jobs are failing intermittently with error "Unable to connect to SQL Server '(local)' The step failed" in Production

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, database-migration, job-scheduling

We have recently migrated and Upgraded our SQL Server and after that we are facing the below issue in Production.

```
Unable to connect to SQL Server '(local)'.  The step failed.
```

Please help. There are hundreds of jobs running on daily basis and we are not allowed to restart the SQL Server Agent in Production since it affects real time transactions highly. We have tried using the below command in SQL Jobs

```
Job Properties-->Steps-->Edit-->Command Window
```

as below

```
 use [DBName] 
 Go
```

followed by the Command Text.

But it also didn't help. But still the next day the jobs are failing with the same error message as below.

```
Unable to connect to SQL Server '(local)'.  The step failed.
```

Please help.

Comment: You say the jobs are failing intermittently, but you also say the jobs are failing again the next day. So do you have specific jobs that fail every day but others work, or do you have jobs that work sometimes but not other times, or ?

Comment: Not only specific jobs . Since there are many hundreds of jobs. And each job has multiple schedules. The jobs are failing intermittently. I have checked for some jobs. i could see the jobs got success as well as failed.But the same job was not failing before the database migration.

Comment: @DancingFool , any help would be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: @DancingFool, If i restart the job then the job gets success.But during the automatic schedules , the job gets success and failure intermittently.

Comment: I don't have any answers for you, I'm sorry. I suggest you try asking on dba.stackexchange.com, as this seem more a dba issue than a programming one. You may get some answers there. I would start by checking time out settings, maybe the old server had a longer setting somewhere and the new one is shorter, so sometimes just runs out of time for the connection to form.